# project does not support its own component

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services

I m working with a big TFS project and under one solution there are many projects(windows services projects). It had reference missing errors before and after i added some .dll files , it fixed. But now the sub projects does not support its own components such as classes used in the same project files.

And also it shows some errors with InitializeComponent();

I replace the class files with new files and pasted original files' codes and debugged but the issue has not fixed, although this has many sub projects i cant do it for all class files as well. I assume the issue may come from because of a not updated xml files of the project. But I don't have a clear idea about it. Please help.

Thanks in Advance